# Trouble deploying to Heroku, module can't resolve

Tags: node.js, heroku

Been trying all day to deploy this. Nothing is working. Ran through the entire node troubleshooter link, everything checks out. The where it says cant resolve module, My code is running fine on all severs and can't find the tmp folder, anywhere. I've only been coding a month. Sorry if this is stupid, but I'd appreciate some help.

```
Matt@DESKTOP-QFMSSDA MINGW64 ~/Desktop/momma-ecommerce (main)
$ git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 442 bytes | 442.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.13.2
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   8.1.2
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.13.2...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.13.2...
remote:        npm 8.1.2 already installed with node
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        added 252 packages, and audited 253 packages in 9s
remote:
remote:        24 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > momma-art-sell@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build -- 
prefix frontend
remote:
remote:        
remote:        added 1445 packages, and audited 1446 packages in 24s
remote:
remote:        171 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        7 moderate severity vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        > frontend@0.1.0 build
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Message' in 
'/tmp/build_4ecd4ad3/frontend/src/screens'
remote:
remote:
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys        
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mjthomasart.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mjthomasart.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mjthomasart.git'``
```